# PowerShell WPF - Binding DataGrid ComboBox to Column In ItemsSource

Tags: wpf, powershell, data-binding, combobox, datagrid

I am trying to populate a ComboBox within a DataGrid with unique values from a given column, however I'm getting unexpected results in that it splits the value from that row into individual characters and populates each ComboBox with said characters.

Here's a simple example script of my issue;

```
$csv = "ID,Fruit,Owner`r`n"
$csv += "1,Apple,Andrew`r`n"
$csv += "2,Banana,Bill`r`n"
$csv += "3,Cherry,Charles`r`n"
$csv += "4,Date,Daniel`r`n"
$csv += "5,Elderberry,Ethan`r`n"

$data = ConvertFrom-Csv $csv

$inputXML = @"
<Window x:Name="DataGridComboTest" x:Class="DataGridComboTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="DataGridComboTest" Width="640" Height="480" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid" Margin="10,10,10,10" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ID}" Header="ID"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Fruit}" Header="Fruit"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Owner}" Header="Owner"/>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Owner Combo">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox
                                SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Owner, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Owner}"
                                Text="{Binding Path=Owner, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                            </ComboBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
"@

$inputXML = $inputXML -replace 'mc:Ignorable="d"','' -replace "x:N",'N'  -replace '^<Win.*', '<Window'
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('presentationframework')
[xml]$XAML = $inputXML

$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
$Form=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )
$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | %{ Set-Variable -Name "$($_.Name)" -Value $Form.FindName($_.Name) -ErrorAction Stop }

$DataGrid.ItemsSource = $data

$Form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

What I'd like to be able to do is select a different owner for each fruit from the existing owners in the table, however instead I'm given a choice of each letter in the adjacent owner's name;

[image: Example screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bind the `ItemsSource` to an `IEnumerable<string>` rather than a scalar `string` (which is an `IEnumerable<char>`).

Try something like this:

```
...
ItemsSource="{DynamicResource owners}"
...

$owners = $data | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Owner -Unique
$Form.Resources.Add("owners", $owners)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Did you test it? It throws an error about a missing parenthesis for me. I've tried shifting it about but I can't make it work.

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction with the DynamicResource binding though. I simplified the owners line to "$owners = $data | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Owner -Unique" which seems to work - I now get all unique owners in each combo.

Comment: @Valiante: I've removed the call to `ToArray()` from my answer. And the fact that you have duplictates is not related to the original question.

Comment: I couldn't in all good conscience upvote or accept it as the answer when it was giving me an error. And I wrote my own answer to demonstrate the full final solution you helped me achieve, with credit to you, but haven't accepted it as the answer as I wanted to give you the opportunity to edit.  Also I mentioned the duplicates simply because I initially had the line without -unique but in a real world scenario this included every name as many times as it appeared in the data, when I wanted just unique owners (as mentioned in the original post).

Comment: @Valiante: Good point. I added the -Unique switch to my answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

With [mm8](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7252182/mm8)'s help I was able to come up with a working script;

```
$csv = "ID,Fruit,Owner`r`n"
$csv += "1,Apple,Andrew`r`n"
$csv += "2,Banana,Bill`r`n"
$csv += "3,Cherry,Charles`r`n"
$csv += "4,Date,Daniel`r`n"
$csv += "5,Elderberry,Ethan`r`n"
$csv += "6,Fig,Bill`r`n"
$csv += "7,Grape,Daniel`r`n"

$data = ConvertFrom-Csv $csv

$inputXML = @"
<Window x:Name="DataGridComboTest" x:Class="DataGridComboTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="DataGridComboTest" Width="640" Height="480" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid" Margin="10,10,10,10" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ID}" Header="ID"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Fruit}" Header="Fruit"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Owner}" Header="Owner"/>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Owner Combo">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox
                                SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Owner, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                ItemsSource="{DynamicResource owners}"
                                Text="{Binding Path=Owner, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                            </ComboBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
"@

$inputXML = $inputXML -replace 'mc:Ignorable="d"','' -replace "x:N",'N'  -replace '^<Win.*', '<Window'
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('presentationframework')
[xml]$XAML = $inputXML

$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
$Form=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )
$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | %{ Set-Variable -Name "$($_.Name)" -Value $Form.FindName($_.Name) -ErrorAction Stop }

$DataGrid.ItemsSource = $data

#$owners = [Linq.Enumerable]::ToArray($data | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Owner)
$owners = $data | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Owner -Unique
$Form.Resources.Add("owners", $owners)

$Form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

The DynamicResource binding was key, but the [Linq.Enumerable] line from mm8's answer threw an error.  However simplifying it to select unique owners from $data resolved this.  I also added a couple of duplicate owners to the source data to more accurately simulate a real-world scenario, hence "-Unique".

[image: DataGridCombo working example]