# Show output in DataGridView from Powershell Script

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, powershell, variables, itemssource

I want to show output in DataGridView that runs from a powershell script:

```
$domain1Groups     = (Get-ADuser -identity $var_userName.Text -server domain1 -Properties MemberOf).MemberOf -Replace 'CN=', '' -Replace ',.*', ''
$domain2Groups     = (Get-ADuser -identity $var_userName.Text -server domain2 -Properties MemberOf).MemberOf -Replace 'CN=', '' -Replace ',.*', ''
$domain3Groups     = (Get-ADuser -identity $var_userName.Text -server domain3 -Properties MemberOf).MemberOf -Replace 'CN=', '' -Replace ',.*', ''
```

with this script I get a list in powershell with 1 column with all memberships from that domain.

Tried with .ItemsSource but I cannot see anything in the DataGridView

```
$var_comboBox.Add_SelectionChanged({



    $item = $var_comboBox.SelectedItem.Content

        if ($item -eq "domain1")
            {$var_DataGridView.ItemsSource = $domain1Groups




    }elseif
           ($item -eq "domain2" )
            {$var_DataGridView.ItemsSource = "$domain2Groups"

}



      else{
           ($item -eq "domain3" )
            $var_DataGridView.ItemSource = "$domain3Groups"

}})

I also want a customized Column that displays the text "Member Of"
```

Comment: The answer here recommends a different object type instead of an array: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58186976/7411885. You may be able to just use `$var_DataGridView.ItemsSource = [Collections.Generic.List[string]]$domain1Groups`

Comment: Answering toon's comment in the answer below, you can directly modify the itemsources of the datagrid, or use $dataGrid.ItemsSource=null to clear it.

Comment: thanks, I already found the answer and indeed this works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define the `DataGrid` like this:

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Member Of" Binding="{Binding}" IsReadOnly="True" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

...you should be able to set the `ItemsSource` property like this:

```
$domain1Groups = (Get-ADuser ...
$dataGrid.ItemsSource = $domain1Groups
```

Comment: Thanks it works. How can i clear the datagrid if i search for another user?